# Angular - Best way to develop a generic function that changes values of multiple ngModel values?

Tags: angular, typescript

I've been working with Angular a couple of weeks and I found a problem that I'm not sure at all on how to do it.

I have a list of around 100 inputs of button type on a page an each of of them reperesent a different value on my database. I linked each of of those to a model as you can see in this snippet :

[Inputs that should be changed on click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epaBR.png)

They all act the same as in when one of those inputs is clicked, the value of that model should change. The problem I'm facing is I can only think of creating one function for every one of the inputs and I don't think that's the best way to do it.

I would like to know for these cases when you have multiple propertys with a same pattern but they all correspond to a different value on db, how could I create a generic function to update them all on Angular

`<div class="col-sm-8">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <input type="button" name="C0R" (click)="changeSpineBoxValue($event)" [(ngModel)]="examData.ExamCervical.C0R" >
                <input type="button" name="C0C" [(ngModel)]="examData.ExamCervical.C0C">
                <input type="button" name="C0L" [(ngModel)]="examData.ExamCervical.C0L">
            </div>
        </div>`

So, as I said, have like 100 of those inputs

```
<input type="button" name="C0L" [(ngModel)]="examData.ExamCervical.C0L">
```

and I would like to create a typescript function that would trigger when clicking any of those inputs. When the input is clicked, the ngmodel value should change. I know I could make something like

```
changeC0LValue(value: number){
 this.examData.ExamCervial.C0L = value;

}
```

But as I have 100 of those inputs, I would need to do 100 functions as the one above (one for each value). I want to know if there's a generic way in order to do this (I don't know if you could send the name of the property and the value in one function and the function could set the value to the ngmodel based on the name), for example :

```
changeInputModelValue( inputname: string, value: number){
     //check for inputname and create the binding
    // set the passed value to the ngmodel based on the name
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some code of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes, I added some more info!

Comment: I suggest to implement it as *ReactiveForms* and then you can simply use the forms `patchValue` function to update many form values simultaneously.

Comment: Do all the properties live in the ExamCervial object?

Comment: @AlmaniaM Yes, they do!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this then:

```
<input type="button" name="C0R" (click)="changeInputModelValue('COR', $event)"/>
changeInputModelValue( inputname: string, value: number){
     this.examData.ExamCervial[inputName] = value;
}
```

Just one way of doing it.

**Method #2**

```
<input type="button" name="C0R" (click)="changeInputModelValue($event)"/>
changeInputModelValue(event: MouseEvent){
     const name = event.target.attributes.name.value;
     const value = event.target.attributes.value.value;
     this.examData.ExamCervial[name] = value;
}
```

Comment: That's awesome! I would like to know if there would be other way of passing the inputname value, so I don't have to write it but instead take it from the input 'name'

Comment: Nevermind, I just found out how with your answer, thanks!

Comment: The second answer assumes your input has a value attribute but hopefully, you get the idea.